# What's the right way to create OsStr(ing) from a FFI-returned slice?

Tags: rust, ffi

I have a function that accepts a callback with args `data: *const u8, length: usize`, that represents some path. What is the right way to create an OsStr(ing) from this?

There's `from_byte_slice` in `OsStrExt`, but seems like it doesn't check if the data is correct WTF-8 or whatever, and it's not clear how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`from_raw_parts`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/fn.from_raw_parts.html) to go from the raw pointer to a slice, then [`OsStrExt::from_bytes`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/ffi/trait.OsStrExt.html):

```
use std::slice;
use std::ffi::OsStr;
use std::os::unix::ffi::OsStrExt; // NOTE PLATFORM-SPECIFIC

fn foo(data: *const u8, length: usize) {
    let slice = unsafe { slice::from_raw_parts(data, length) };
    let os_str = OsStr::from_bytes(slice);
}

fn main() {
}
```

Note that **this is *nix-specific** - Windows and *nix do not represent paths is the same way (turns out this stuff is reasonably complicated!). If your API actually is returning a UTF-8 string, then you could use the normal string methods to convert the raw components to a `&str` and then to an `OsStr(ring)`.

For further information about [`WTF-8`](https://simonsapin.github.io/wtf-8/), I highly recommend the excellent docs.

Comment: Is that still true for 1.0? `<OsStr as std::os::unix::ffi::OsStrExt>::from_bytes(CStr::from_ptr(c_path).to_bytes())` compiles, but it's uuugly.

Comment: @porneL I've updated the example for 1.0, but it seems like your case will still have some sharp edges :-)